# How to connect Qt action with a function

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I am trying to make a Qt-based GUI, and I want to connect one menu item with a function, I meant that after click on a menu item this function will be called. I tried it like this, but it doesn`t work, after click on menu idem I do not see my cout print. What I am doing wrong?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    map my_map;

    connect(ui->actionSave_Map, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(saveMap()));

}

void MainWindow::saveMap(map& my_map)
{
    std::cout << "clicked to save" << std::endl;
    my_map.saveMap();
}
```

.h file

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "map.h"

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void setMapPreferences();
    void generateMap();
    void drawMap();

public slots:
    void saveMap(map& my_map);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**in console there is an error after click :**

```
Object::connect: No such slot MainWindow::saveMap(map& my_map) in ../map_generator/mainwindow.cpp:19
```

Comment: Is `saveMap()` a slot ? Are you checking the output on the console ?

Comment: Yes I am checking output on a console, and I think it is a slot, I added .h file to my post.

Comment: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( map );` - near your map declaration. And remove an arguments from `saveMap` slot (or use `QSignalMapper`).

Comment: @SaZ, it is working now, thank you sir.

Comment: That saveMap slot has map& reference parameter and the connect for the signal does not provide that mandatory parameter.

Answer (score 5):

In that case, it is simple when use lambada.
Replace:

`connect(ui->actionSave_Map, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(saveMap()));`

with

```
connect(ui->actionSave_Map, &QAction::triggered, [=]() {
  saveMap(my_map);
});
```

after that, sure you add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x` to your `.pro` file